# What does "UserWarning: No PROJECT_APPS settings, coverage gathered over all apps" mean?

Tags: django, jenkins, django-jenkins

So I am researching and testing the continuous integration of Django and Jenkins for my company. I successfully connected them but this warning keeps popping up. I already tried googling for this and to my dismay did not find what I was looking for.

So I read in some articles that I needed to insert a line of code into a config file but I am not sure if this is right. Below is the code

```
JENKINS_TASKS = (
    'django_jenkins.tasks.run_pep8',
    'django_jenkins.tasks.run_pyflakes',
    'django_jenkins.tasks.run_jslint',
    'django_jenkins.tasks.run_csslint',
    'django_jenkins.tasks.run_sloccount'
)
```

The problem is, my Django and Jenkins would not run if I put this in settings.py so I am utterly confused on to where I should put this. The documentation for Django-Jenkins only stated that to enable it you need to install on Jenkins server manually and I did not find any guide on how to install it so I am doing my last choice of asking here.

Here is my settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ')7f_a==zt^d9h6n%!y-$#_(2u&12vw9fd9g1q*d4^&08hh^k(p'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django_jenkins',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Manila'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Please, can you provide the full `settings.py`?

Comment: @HigorRossato
I updated my post regarding my settings.py